# sp-request : trying get file details from sharepoint returns ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, npm, sharepoint

I have the following code that successfully uploads test.sspkg to my sharepoint app catalog.  Now I'm trying to use sp-request to prove that it's actually there.
But I'm getting an ECONNREFUSED error.

**Error message**

This shows the error:

```
[14:24:15] INFO: Checking if file (test.sppkg) is checked out
[14:24:15] INFO: File checkout type: 0
[14:24:17] Published file 1482ms
[14:24:17] And we're done...
trying to retrieve: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/JJTest/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@FileUrl)/$value?@FileUrl='%2Fsites%2FJJTest%2FAppCatalog%2Ftest.sppkg'
errored out
{ GotError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at onError (/src/myplugins/node_modules/got/dist/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:140:29)
    at ClientRequest.request.on.error (/src/myplugins/node_modules/got/dist/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:157:17)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit.args (/src/myplugins/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:43:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14) name: 'RequestError', code: 'ECONNREFUSED' }
```

**Package**

This is the node package I'm using to call the SP API:

"dependencies": {
"sp-request": "^3.0.0"
}

**Code:**

```
    const sprequest = require('sp-request');

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          gulp
          .src(folderLocation)
          .pipe(
            spsync({
              username: uname,
              password: pwd,
              site: siteCatalogUrl + "/",
              libraryPath: catalogName,
              publish: true,
              verbose: true
            }))
          .on("finish", () => {
              var spr = sprequest.create({ username: uname, password: pwd });
      
            //https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/JJTest/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/JJTest/AppCatalog/test.sppkg')
              var filepath = `${siteCatalogUrl}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@FileUrl)/$value?@FileUrl='${encodeURIComponent("/sites/JJTest/AppCatalog/test.sppkg")}'`;
              console.log('trying to retrieve: ' + filepath);
              var retrieveFileUrl = filepath;
              
              spr.get(filepath, {
                encoding:null
            })
            .then(data => {
                expect(fileContent.equals(data.body)).is.true;
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(data => {
              console.log('errored out')
              console.log(data)
              reject();
            });

            resolve();
          });  
      });
```

What I've tried:

I have tried just copying parts of the output from my console directly into the browser.  Specifically, this is the output i get from my debug print statement:

```
trying to retrieve: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/JJTest/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl/(@FileUrl)/$value?@FileUrl='%2Fsites%2FJJTest%2FAppCatalog%2Ftest.sppkg'
errored out
```

Pasting this:
[https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/JJTest/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/JJTest/AppCatalog/test.sppkg')](https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/JJTest/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/JJTest/AppCatalog/test.sppkg%27))

into a browser as the URL works.  It returns the details of the file to me.

Can you tell me where I've gone wrong?  maybe the syntax of substituting the @FileUrl?

Answer (score 0):

I am using gulp version 3.9.1.  And I just did a install latest of chai and sp-request.

But tried changing the specific versions to:

```
"sp-request": "^2.1.3"
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-spsync-creds": "2.3.8",
"chai": "3.5.0"
```

And now, it's happy!  it worked!